# How to get all data of table by use of sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have postgres table name `tests` which contain few records, now I want to fetch all record of this table but unable because its provides only `id,createdAt and updatedAt`.

So either I have to provide an object which contain column name that I don't want, I wish it should be dynamic so after this if I pass another table name it will provide data of that.
I tried this but it returns null array of object

```
Project.findAll(attributes: ['*']
}).then(function(project) {
  console.log("select_data: " + JSON.stringify(project));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what the question / problem is here, but it sounds like when you're defining your model, you might not have included all the column names of the table in your model definition. Here's what it should look like:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const test = sequelize.define('test', {
    my_column: DataTypes.STRING,
    my_other_column: DataTypes.STRING,
    my_boolean_column: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'tests',
  })

  return test
}
```

Notice each column of the table is explicitly defined in the model.

Comment: Exactly I didn't provide each column name because I have 45 tables so I can't create 45 models, I want it dynamically that I have done during table create and insert value without specific model.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. I don't think sequelize can do that.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer, the library does not support usage without first creating models.